# Truncate Statement Taking Too much time

Tags: sql, azure, truncate

I have a table Which has more than 1 million records, I have created a stored Procedure to insert data in that table, before Inserting the data I need to truncate the table but truncate is taking too long.

I have read on some links that if a table is used by another person or some locks are applied then truncate takes too long time but here I am the only user and I have applied no locks on that.

Also no other transactions are open when I tried to truncate the table.

As my database is on SQL Azure I am not supposed to drop the indexes as it does not allow me to insert the data without an index.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL Azure, but truncate statements should be nearly instant. In SQL Server 2008 R2, I had a table with 360M rows laying around that I needed to drop. Truncated instantly. Be sure that there is no blocking session on the table. One of the groups I work with as standard procedure drops and recreates all tables and indexes instead of truncating, you may be able to try that. But this is not something that should take a long time.

Comment: I also used that approach to drop the table, but again creating the table it takes too long time, right now my query without using truncate it takes 15 mins to do all the operation but when i add truncate it takes more than a hour to complete the execution

Comment: Can you post the entire script? It sounds like there's something else going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop all the indexes from the table and then truncate, if you want to insert the data then insert data and after inserting the data recreate the indexes

Answer (score -1):

When deleting from Azure you can get into all sorts of trouble, but truncate is almost always an issue of locking. If you can't fix that you can always do this trick when deleting from Azure.

```
declare @iDeleteCounter int =1
while @iDeleteCounter > 0
begin
    begin transaction deletes;
    with deleteTable as
    (
        select top 100000 * from  mytable where mywhere
    )
    delete from deleteTable
    commit transaction deletes
    select @iDeleteCounter = count(1) from   mytable where mywhere

    print 'deleted 100000 from table' 

end
```